# Why boost::assign::list_of isn't working with pair<string, vector<string>>?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost

I don't understand why this doesn't work (Visual C++ 2012):

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    pair<string, vector<string> >("^", boost::assign::list_of<string>("rules"));
}
```

The error is:

```
include\utility(138) : error C2668: 'std::vector<_Ty>::vector' : ambiguous call to overloaded function with [ _Ty=std::string ]
include\vector(786): could be 'std::vector<_Ty>::vector(std::vector<_Ty> &&)' with [ _Ty=std::string ]
include\vector(693): or       'std::vector<_Ty>::vector(unsigned int)' with [ _Ty=std::string ]
while trying to match the argument list '(boost::assign_detail::generic_list<T>)' with [ T=std::string ]
test.cpp(12) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::pair<const char(&)[2],boost::assign_detail::generic_list<T>>(_Other1,_Other2 &&,void **)' being compiled
with
[
    _Ty1=std::string,
    _Ty2=std::vector<std::string>,
    T=std::string,
    _Other1=const char (&)[2],
    _Other2=boost::assign_detail::generic_list<std::string>
]
test.cpp(12) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::pair<const char(&)[2],boost::assign_detail::generic_list<T>>(_Other1,_Other2 &&,void **)' being compiled
with
[
    _Ty1=std::string,
    _Ty2=std::vector<std::string>,
    T=std::string,
    _Other1=const char (&)[2],
    _Other2=boost::assign_detail::generic_list<std::string>
]
```

I can't decipher why it's trying to access an `unsigned int` overload... any ideas?

Comment: That because template constructor is not suitable too.
Try: pair<string, vector<string> >("^", boost::assign::list_of(std::string("rules")));
or pair<string, vector<string> >("^", boost::assign::list_of<std::string>("rules"));

Comment: @kassak: Why `unsigned int` though? I'm not having much trouble working around the problem, but rather understanding why it's happening in the first place.

Comment: Compiler could not find suitable constructor and just lists all one-argument constructors.


And it could not find constructor, because result of list_of<char*> is not convertiable to vector<std::string>

Comment: @kassak: `pair<string, vector<string> >("^", boost::assign::list_of<string>("rules"))` doesn't work either; I'll update the question.

Comment: hm...that works fine for me in vs2008

Comment: Very strange. Does explicit cast helps?
pair<string, vector<string> > aa("^", (vector<string>)boost::assign::list_of<string>("rules"))

Not as solution, just test =)

Comment: @kassak: Almost... now I get `test.cpp(13) : error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'boost::assign_detail::generic_list<T>' to 'std::vector<_Ty>' with [ T=std::string ] and [ _Ty=std::string ] No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous`. It seems fine on 2008 here too, but 2010 and 2012 give these errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because a new `pair` constructor was added in C++11 to accept universal references. As a result, this code will fail in VS2012 (which added this constructor) and in GCC when in C++11 mode.

**In C++03**:

The `pair<T1,T2>` constructor was:

```
pair( const T1& x, const T2& y ) : first(x), second(y) {}
```

In this case, `T2 == vector<string>`.

A `generic_list` object (the object returned by `list_of`) has a template conversion operator:

```
template <class Container>
operator Container() const;
```

When you pass in `generic_list` as a parameter, it tries to convert the `generic_list` object to a `vector<string>`, since that is what the constructor expects, and this succeeds.

**In C++11**:

This `pair<T1,T2>` constructor was added:

```
template< class U1, class U2 >
pair( U1&& x, U2&& y ) : first(std::forward<U1>(x)), second(std::forward<U2>(y))
```

Now when you pass in a `generic_list` object, it will be passed in as `generic_list&&`. When it tries to call the `second` (of type `vector<string>`) constructor with this object, it doesn't know which of these constructors to call:

```
explicit vector(size_type count, [more params with default values])
vector(const vector& other);
```

Since `generic_list` can be converted to both `size_type` and `vector<string>`. This results in the compilation error.

**Fix/Workaround**:

A possible fix is to use the `convert_to_container` method and specify the target type:

```
pair<string, vector<string> >("^", boost::assign::list_of<string>("rules").convert_to_container<vector<string> >());
```

Another option is to use `make_pair` and explicitly specify its template parameters.

Comment: A couple minutes ago I thought you'd nailed the problem, but now I'm not so sure. Why would `pair<string, vector<string> >("^", boost::assign::list_of<string>("rules"));` be calling `vector`'s explicit constructor?

Comment: @Mehrdad: You're right, I was wrong about that. I changed my answer and I think it's correct now.

Comment: Ahhhh, so it's still a problem with the explicit constructor, but it's due to the forwarding constructor! Interesting, thanks. By the way, I wonder if this really means that "perfect" forwarding is still impossible in C++, given that it doesn't let you handle explicit-ness? =O Maybe I should post that as a question!

Comment: Funny, before I figure that out, I ran into another weird issue. Here's a link if you're curious/interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950556

Comment: @Mehrdad: The constructor being `explicit` isn't relevant, the same would happen without `explicit`. The issue is that in the C++03 version, an implicit conversion is performed from `generic_list` to `vector`, which can only happen by converting it directly to a vector, since an implicit conversion can only do one conversion. In the C++11 version the `vector` constructor is called explicitly, so a conversion can be done from `generic_list` to either `vector` or `size_type`.

Answer (score 1):

So instead of this:

```
("^", boost::assign::list_of<string>("rules"))
```

I have to write:

```
("^", boost::assign::list_of<string>("rules").convert_to_container<vector<string> >());
```

Makes it kind of unreadable ...
I added Yet Another template:

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> vect(const boost::assign_detail::generic_list<T>& gen_list)
{ return gen_list.convert_to_container<std::vector<T> >(); }
```

and can write it now as:

```
("^", vect(boost::assign::list_of<string>("rules")))
```

which is still not nice, but closer to what you started with.