# Conversion operator + conversion constructor = unintuitive behavior?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, implicit-conversion

I don't understand why the code below prints `struct Value` instead of `int` (which implies the conversion constructor is converting to `Value` instead of `int`). (Visual C++ 2012)

Why is this happening? Why does the compiler completely ignore the `Value(int)` constructor?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_info>

using namespace std;

struct Value { Value(int) { } };

struct Convertible
{
    template<class T>
    operator T() const
    { throw typeid(T).name(); }
};

int main()
{
    try { Value w((Convertible())); }
    catch (char const *s) { cerr << s << endl; }
}
```

### Edit:

Even more bizarre is [this](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1htnJu%242) (this time it's C++11 only, on GCC 4.7.2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

struct Value
{
    Value(Value const &) = delete;
    Value(int) { }
};

struct Convertible
{
    template<class T>
    operator T() const
    { throw typeid(T).name(); }
};

int main()
{
    try { Value w((Convertible())); }
    catch (char const *s) { cerr << s << endl; }
}
```

Which gives:

```
source.cpp: In function 'int main()':
source.cpp:21:32: error: call of overloaded 'Value(Convertible)' is ambiguous
source.cpp:21:32: note: candidates are:
source.cpp:9:3: note: Value::Value(int)
source.cpp:8:3: note: Value::Value(const Value&) <deleted>
```

If the copy constructor is deleted, then why is there any ambiguity?!

Comment: Why would it print `int`? You are trying to create an instance of `Value`, so you get a conversion to `Value`.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I'm calling `Value`'s constructor, and its argument is of type `int`, so why isn't `Convertible()` being converted to `int`? Why is the implicit copy constructor completely hiding my explicitly-defined constructor, instead of causing an ambiguity error?

Comment: http://liveworkspace.org/code/3ZUTMY$0 ... which compiler you use?

Comment: @Mehrdad it's going to be converted to `int` and then to `Value`.

Comment: @ForEveR: Visual C++... I wonder if this is a compiler bug?

Comment: @TonyTheLion: If it's indeed going to be converted to `int` as you say, then I should be seeing `int`, not `struct Value`, on stderr.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I'm not sure if this is related, but see my update.

Comment: I understand the question now, but what you call "bizarre" is normal: deleted functions are not removed from overload resolution. They simply make the program ill-formed if they are selected. This a feature.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Okay, I do find that bizarre, but if that's indeed the case, then why didn't they cause ambiguity in the first case? It seems like it's impossible to tell the compiler to pick a non-copy constructor... is that a feature or a bug? And why is it inconsistent?

Comment: @Mehrdad with GCC there is, even in the first case. It seems to be a compiler bug.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Huh... is it even *possible* to call a constructor other than the copy ctor from a templated conversion operator?

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/774730/templated-conversion-constructor-always-calls-copy-constructor-even-when-ambiguous

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Seems to be a feature, not a bug! See the Connect link above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the first example Visual Studio is incorrect; the call is ambiguous.  gcc in C++03 mode prints:

```
source.cpp:21:34: error: call of overloaded 'Value(Convertible)' is ambiguous
source.cpp:21:34: note: candidates are:
source.cpp:9:5: note: Value::Value(int)
source.cpp:6:8: note: Value::Value(const Value&)
```

Recall that a copy constructor is implicitly defaulted.  The governing paragraph is **13.3.1.3 Initialization by constructor [over.match.ctor]**:

> When objects of class type are direct-initialized [...], overload resolution selects the constructor. For direct-initialization, the candidate functions are all the constructors of the class of the object being initialized.

In the second example, deleted functions participate equally in overload resolution; they only affect compilation once overloads have been resolved, when a program that selects a deleted function is ill-formed.  The motivating example in the standard is of a class that can only be constructed from floating-point types:

```
struct onlydouble {
  onlydouble(std::intmax_t) = delete;
  onlydouble(double);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried your code (on the Visual Studio version only).

Since you have a built-in copy-CTOR, I guess your main is equal to:

```
int main()
{
    try { Value w((struct Value)(Convertible())); }
    catch (char const *s) { cerr << s << endl; }
}
```

The compiler has chosen to use your copy CTOR, rather than Value(int).

Changing it to:

```
int main()
{
    try { Value w((int)(Convertible())); }
    catch (char const *s) { cerr << s << endl; }
}
```

It printed "int".

Comment: Look at the first code snippet again. The OP defined their own c'tor. So There should be no copy-c'tor.

Comment: @DimaRudnik - Yes, there is a default copy c'tor, if you haven't implemented one yourself.